# Types of property 'WebkitBoxOrient' are incompatible

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

What is wrong with this?

```
if (isClampSupported) {
  const clampStyling = {
    display: '-webkit-box',
    WebkitLineClamp: lines,
    WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
  };
  return (
    <div style={clampStyling}>{children}</div>
  )
}
```

The `style=` is red-squiggly, showing:

> Type '{ display: string; WebkitLineClamp: number | undefined; WebkitBoxOrient: string; overflow: string; textOverflow: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
> Types of property 'WebkitBoxOrient' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'BoxOrient | undefined'.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(1841, 9): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'
> (JSX attribute) HTMLAttributes.style?: React.CSSProperties | undefined

How to fix?

[image]

If I change it to a lowercase `webkitBoxOrient`, it logs a warning in the console saying:

> Warning: Unsupported vendor-prefixed style property webkitBoxOrient. Did you mean WebkitBoxOrient?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like inline style:

```
if (isClampSupported) {
  return (
    <div style={{
    display: '-webkit-box',
    WebkitLineClamp: lines,
    WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
  }}>{children}</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple:

```js
...
WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical' as const,
...
```